# How to check object instance is inherited from Abstract Class in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance, abstract-class

I have below Abstract Class

```
abstract class AbstractPerson{
  ......
}
```

I have inherited AbstractPerson into Account

```
class Account extends AbstractPerson{
  ......
}
```

Now I am going to make object of class

```
$account= new Account()
```

I am wondering how to check `$account` object is extended from AbstractPerson class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), and two methods getParentClass() & isAbstract().

Here's a working example of what you need.

```
$accountReflection     = new ReflectionClass('Account');
$parentReflection     = new ReflectionClass($accountReflection->getParentClass()->getName());
$isAbstract           = $parentReflection->isAbstract(); // return true of false
```

Comment: What is $testClass?

Comment: I fix it, check it.

Comment: $accountReflection::getParentClass(); this syntax is wrong  getting error

Comment: I have edited accessor, but still $isAbstract returns false;

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if ($account instanceof AbstractPerson) {
   echo 'AbstractPerson';
}
```